# Module not found Error even after changing python version

Tags: python, django, pypdf

[image]

I am trying to import PyPDF2 , into my django project ,I am getting ModuleNotFoundError I checked its properly installed  inside virtualEnv , here I am even trying to change Python version from visual studio extension.

How can I change the python version from 3.9.0 to 3.5.0 to check PyPDF2 if it works with 3.5.0 . In visual studio extension I changed python version but why its still using 3.9.0 when checked with python --version

if I use num2words still I get same ModuleNotFoundError.

[image]

Comment: did you create a new environment or you change the version in an existing environment?

Comment: No environment created I just downloaded python .exe file and installed it,please help I am struggling since almost 2 days

Comment: did you change the environment variables/ Path variable? Set to a new exe of your python.

Comment: does the 'pip list' command show the PyPDF2 package?

Comment: Yes I installed with option add to path, I updated the question by adding another image also

Comment: yes it shows PyPDF2 1.26.0 in the list